# Scaling SpriteKit game

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

What is the best way to aspect image fit the blue box? The game is pixel-based, so I would like to keep the pixellated look to it as well.

[image]

Comment: ...use the Aspect Fit scale mode?

Comment: Do I call it on self.view? Will this scale all the nodes?

Answer (score 0):

According with the actual Swift 2.2 you can find:

```
@available(iOS 7.0, *)
public enum SKSceneScaleMode : Int {

    case Fill /* Scale the SKScene to fill the entire SKView. */
    case AspectFill /* Scale the SKScene to fill the SKView while preserving the scene's aspect ratio. Some cropping may occur if the view has a different aspect ratio. */
    case AspectFit /* Scale the SKScene to fit within the SKView while preserving the scene's aspect ratio. Some letterboxing may occur if the view has a different aspect ratio. */
    case ResizeFill /* Modify the SKScene's actual size to exactly match the SKView. */
}
```

You can do it for example in your viewController :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let scene = PreloadScene(fileNamed:"PreloadScene") {
            // Configure the view.
            let skView = self.view as! SKView
            ...
            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFit 
            ...
            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }
```

Or transiting from a `SKScene` to another `SKScene`:

```
let transition = SKTransition.doorsOpenVerticalWithDuration(0.5)
let nextScene = MainScene(size: self.scene!.size)
nextScene.scaleMode = .AspectFit
self.scene?.view?.presentScene(nextScene, transition: transition)
```

Comment: For some reason AspectFit doesn't give me any letterboxing and seems exactly the same as AspectFill.

Comment: Try to add some code to your question to better understand your issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can scale your sprite fit to blue box.

```
func fitToBlueBox(node:SKSpriteNode, blueBox:SKSpriteNode) {
    let actualScale = min(blueBox.size.width/node.size.width, blueBox.size.height/node.size.height)
    node.setScale(actualScale);
}
```